# Hide/unhide combobox based on a text box

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-forms

I have a form in access that works in this way:

User select an ID of a product
VBA code searches in the database and fill some textboxes in the form.
For example:
User select ID 1
Textbox 1 is filled with: fruit

My problem is, i have a combobox with options to select like "banana" or "apple" or "grape". This combobox is visible at the form, but i want it to be invisible and only appears if the textbox 1 is filled with "fruit".

In the design view, i set the combobox's visibility to "no", so it does not appear anymore in the form. Then, i wrote this code:

```
Private Sub textbox1_AfterUpdate()
  If Me.textbox1 = "fruit" Then
      Me.LabelOfTheCombobox.Visible = True
      Me.Combobox.Visible = True
  Else
      Me.LabelOfTheCombobox.Visible = False
      Me.Combobox.Visible = False
  End if
End Sub
```

But it doesnt work, when the textbox is filled with "fruit", the combobox remains invisible.
Can you help me fix this code?

Comment: Property setting will apply to ALL instances of textbox. Therefore this won't work nice for Continuous or Datasheet form. In which case, best can do is enable/disable with Conditional Formatting. Otherwise, see nothing wrong with code.

Comment: What control gets focus after textbox1?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK. From what you have said, that putting "fruit" in the textbox doesn't cause the combobox to display, then my guess would be that the If-test is failing. Perhaps you could try trimming both sides of the textbox before the comparison. You should also pay attention to the case. Try forcing the case of the textbox to lower case to match the string constant.